# Finding and listing text from one Json file that is not in the other Json file

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am trying to find all the ids in one of my JSON files that do not exist in my other JSON file.

I have not tried anything yet, since I am not sure how to approach it.

First JSON file example:

```
{
    "id": "TestLinkOne",
    "displayText": "Test Link Text",
},
```

Second JSON file example:

```
{
    "id": "Test",
    "response": [
      {
        "text": "Hello",
        "ids": [
          "TestLinkOne",
          "TestLinkTwo"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

I would like to bring back a list of all the ids in my first JSON file that are not in my second JSON file.

Comment: You want to do this in backend, right? Well, JSON is just a fancy string. You could manipulate the strings, either by a REGEX or string.Substring(/*args here*/); or the like and then compare the arrays/lists/hashsets for union/difference.